# Playa Customisation: Include all entries for coparents tag

Tags: playa

How can I  arrange it so that the current entry is included with the others, but in the correct order when using the coparents tag. Currently I have got:

```
 <h3>Other scenes</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            {scene_preview}<img src="{url:Listing}" alt="{title}" class="{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}grey{/if}" />{/scene_preview}
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i> {if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}<strong>Coming:</strong>{/if} {entry_date format="%d %M"} <span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i> Viewing</span></p>
        </div>
        {exp:playa:coparents field="movie_title"}
            <div class="span3">
                {if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}<a href="{title_permalink='movie/scene'}">{/if}{scene_preview}<img src="{url:Listing}" alt="{title}" class="{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}grey{/if}" />{/scene_preview}{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}</a>{/if}
                <h4>{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}<a href="{title_permalink='movie/scene'}">{/if}{title}{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}</a>{/if}</h4>
                <i class="icon-calendar"></i> {if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}<strong>Coming:</strong>{/if} {entry_date format="%d %M"}</p>
            </div>
        {/exp:playa:coparents}
    </div>
```

But this solution is not ideal, as it puts the current entry being viewed at the beginning of the row and not in the original order. Can I include ALL entries with the same co-parent and display them in the original order?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would actually work and I don't have a site with the right setup to test it right now but you could try this:

```
<h3>Other scenes</h3>
<div class="row">

    {embed="includes/_coparents"
        all_coparents="{entry_id}|{exp:playa:coparent_ids field="movie_title"}"
    }
</div>
```

Your `includes/_coparents` embed would look something like this:

```
{exp:playa:coparents coparent_id="{embed:all_coparents}"}
    <div class="span3">
        {if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}<a href="{title_permalink='movie/scene'}">{/if}{scene_preview}<img src="{url:Listing}" alt="{title}" class="{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}grey{/if}" />{/scene_preview}{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}</a>{/if}
        <h4>{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}<a href="{title_permalink='movie/scene'}">{/if}{title}{if '{entry_date format="%U"}' < '{current_time format="%U"}'}</a>{/if}</h4>
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i> {if '{entry_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'}<strong>Coming:</strong>{/if} {entry_date format="%d %M"}</p>
    </div>
{/exp:playa:coparents}
```

Like I say, totally untested but it might just work.

Comment: The principle of this solution also enabled me to include an entry in a list of its siblings.